# Read-only etherpad

Tags: centos, haproxy

Is there any way to make an etherpad site read-only? 
I know I can disable new pads creation in the settings.json file ("editOnly" : true), but this doesn't seem to limit users from altering existing contents. I just want to decommission the site from active use but leave it online for lookups to legacy entries - but no modifications on these.

Platform: CentOS 6, proxy: HAProxy; MySQL back-end.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get a read only ID for a pad with the `getReadOnlyId()` method of the API: https://etherpad.org/doc/v1.7.0/

It returns a random-looking ID that you then use in lieu of the original one, e.g. `http://my.etherpad.net/p/foobarbazreadonlyid`.

But there doesn't seem to be a way to make an existing pad read only while retaining the URL, however.